# How to force locate.updatedb to index files in ~/iCloud?

Tags: macos, command-line

On my Mac (macOS 13.0), the `locate.updatedb` command does not index any files in `~/iCloud`. This issue does not appear to be dependent on macOS version. It has been occurring since I started using iCloud. It also does not appear to be related to permissions, as all files are `drwxr-xr-x@`. Is this is a known issues? And is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

`locate.updatedb` is not present anymore on macOS 13. Are you using Homebrew or `gupdatedb`?

Also the official iCloud folder is located at `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs` or are you simply referring to a custom folder?

If you are referring to Spotlight, it might be better just to request a full [reindex](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716) of Spotlight and check if your `iCloud` folder is not accidentally in your Spotlight privacy exclude list.